# How Fibonacci sequence works in rabbits problem?

Tags: recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

I can't understand the explanation in my textbook.

In the following text $f_{n-1}$ is explained as the number on the island the previous month while $f_{n-2}$ is explained as the newborn pairs. But say $n=5,$

$$f_5=f_4+f_3,$$

in this case $f_3$ is not newborn pairs any more, it consists of both newborn rabbits and adult rabbits. Could anyone give me some advice?

[image]

---

### Edit:

Ok, my current idea is that, observe

$$f_n = f_{n-1}+f_{n-2},$$

- The difference between $f_{n-1}$ and $f_{n-2}$ should be the newborn rabbit pairs.
- The intersection between $f_{n-1}$ and $f_{n-2}$ is somewhat complicated, but pairs in this set should have been alive for at least 2 months, in the perspective of the current($n$-th) month.

Now the calculation of $f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$ will double the intersection and include the newborn pairs.

So maybe this could be how it work?

Comment: Suppose you are considering the $n^{th}$ month; the pairs of rabbits in the $(n-2)^{th}$ month are now all adults, and will consequently give birth to an equal number of pairs - the newborns. We also have to count the pairs of adults there are now; but this equals the pairs in the $(n-1)^{th}$ month; as the newborns in the $(n-1)^{th}$ month would now also be adults.

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe: But when $n$ is large, $n-2$ will not consists of all young rabbits?

Comment: No, I meant that some will be adults, and some young; but after 2 months (the $n^{th})$ they will all reproduce

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe: Ok thank you for the idea:) I've edited my post and updated my current thought.

Comment: The difference is the number of newborns in the $(n-1)^{th}$ month; but they do not give birth (in the $n^{th}$ month)$. And the 'intersection' as you said are the ones who will give birth, so their number will double

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe: So do you meant it's correct?

Comment: I just wanted to clarify the difference part; but yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be "overthinking" this. In the (very unrealistic) rabbit population model, the rabbits never die. So in month 5 all the pairs of rabbits alive in month 4 are still alive - this is $f_4$ pairs - plus there is a newborn pair born to each pair of rabbits that were alive in month 3 - so there are an additional $f_3$ pairs. Hence

$f_5 = f_4 + f_3$

and, in general

$f_n = f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$

and the number of newborn pairs born in month $n$ is just $f_{n-2}$.